# Twilio Chat Client - How To Retrieve Media Image Message in Android

Tags: java, android, twilio-api

I am new with Twilio Chat, I have problem with Media image. 
Anyone can guide me How to display image message of Chat that already sent by user.

Comment: check this: https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/media-support#creating-a-media-message

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan thank you, but that doc still cant help me

Comment: check this, it’s still under development but may be help you https://github.com/ShwetaChauhan18/TwilioProgrammableChat